# Como se chama o efeito Pinterest de conteúdo?

Tags: php, html, css, facebook

Gostaria de perguntar pra vós como se chama o efeito **Pinterest** de conteúdo que alguns itens ficam mas em cima, outros itens ficam mais embaixo, nada com uma linha horizontal definida? Pode ser visto a seguir: [image: imagem exemplo]

Comment: Mosaico? Não sei se isso tem nome, mas foi popularizado pelo [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com), que surgiu como plugin para jQuery e hoje não depende mais dessa biblioteca. O site do Masonry chama isso de *cascading grid layout*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para efeito de pesquisa e busca, trata-se apenas de um layout em multicolunas "pinterest like". Chamá-lo de "layout em grid", como os desenvolvedores do Mansory fazem na apresentação do plugin, gera confusão com uma técnica de estilos muito bem definida e conhecida, e que nada tem a ver com o "efeito" do Pinterest.